# Ayuda con programa de preguntar palabras

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa para preguntarme palabras de francés.

En realidad, he intentado algo pero creo que está todo mal.

Quiero preguntar:
 - cuántas palabras quieres que te pregunte?

Esto es para que ponga `Palabra: user_input ; Traduccion: user_input` las veces que el usuario quiera.

Por otro lado, me gustaría que las respuestas del usuario se guardasen y luego preguntarlas al azár.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora, que no es nada porque no se cómo seguir (he empezado hace nada):

```
print ('Cuantas palabras quieres que te pregunte?')
numeropalabras = int(input(": "))

print (numeropalabras * "Palabra: ")
palabra = str(input(numeropalabras * ": ")
print (numeropalabras * "Traduccion: ")
traduccion = str(input(numeropalabras * ": ")
```

**Actualización:**

De acuerdo a las respuestas e intentado completar mi programa y ahora tendo:

```
diccionario = {}

numeropalabras = int(input("¿Cuantas palabras quieres que te pregunte?: "))

for i in range(numeropalabras):
    palabra = str(input("\nIngrese su palabra en español: "))
    traduccion = str(input("Ingrese la traducción al francés de {0}: ".format(palabra)))
    diccionario[palabra] = traduccion

for palabra, traduccion in diccionario.items():
    print('\nCuál es la traducción  "{0}"?'.format(palabra, traduccion))
    respuesta =  str(input("\nIngrese su respuesta en francés: "))
    if respuesta == "{1}":
        print("Su respuesta es correcta.")
    else:
        print("Su respuesta es incorrecta.")
```

He añadido una cosilla, para que compare si la respuesta es correcta o incorrecta. Cómo se comparan 2 strings en Python? Me da todo el rato incorrecta.

Comment: Hola Juan, lo primero que necesitas es usar un `for` para pedir cada palabra y su traduccion. Para almacenarlas lo mejor  es usar un [`diccionario`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) para almacenar las parejas palabra-traduccion. Además como los dicionarios no mantienen el orden de entrada luego cuando accedas a el para preguntar te dara las palabras 'al azar'.

Comment: me podrias dar un ejemplo? Porque no lo entiendo del todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola! Antes de nada te recomendaría mirarte un poco algún manual de python ya que te va a venir de lujo, y vas a poder avanzar mucho más.

```
palabras = dict()
print ('Cuantas palabras quieres que te pregunte?')
numeropalabras = int(input(": "))
i = 0
while(i < numeropalabras):
    palabraEsp = raw_input("Introduzca palabra en Esp:")
    palabraFra = raw_input("Introduzca traduccion en Frances:")
    palabras.update({palabraEsp:palabraFra})
    i= i+1

print palabras
```

A partir de aquí seguro que puedes progresar por tu cuenta, animo!

Edit: Si se usa una versión de Python 3.X. utilizar **input** en vez de la función **raw_input**.

Comment: me pone que raw_input no esta definido

Comment: Que raro, dime que versión de python usas. Porque a mi me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Vale, mea culpa. Probablemente estes utilizando Python 3.X así que utiliza solo input y no raw_input. Comentame a ver si te funciona para editarlo.

Comment: Con input funciona, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Como solo se aprende programando y con dolores de cabeza no quiero dartelo hecho sino darte algunas ideas por lo que te voy a mostrar solo como pedir las palabras y alamcenarlas en un [`diccionario`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

A grandes rasgos un `diccionario` en `Python` es una estructura de datos que permite guardar un **conjunto no ordenado** de pares **clave-valor**, teniendo en cuenta que las claves son **únicas** dentro de un mismo diccionario. Se asemeja mucho al diccionario de palabras y definiciones de una lengua.

La forma sencilla de crear un diccionario es usando `{}` y dentro poner las parejas clave-valor separadas por una coma. Cada pareja clave-valor se separa por dos puntos. Un ejemplo sería:

```
mi_diccionario = {'perro':'animal', 'limonero':'planta'}
```

Para añadir nuevas parejas se hace asi:

```
mi_dicionario[clave] = valor
```

Si esto queda mas u menos claro, en tu caso lo que hariamos es capturar con un `input()` las palabras a ingresar, declaramos un diccionario vacío y dentro de un `for` pedimos cada palabra y su traducción y lo añadimos al diccionario:

```
diccionario = {} #diccionario vacio, podria declarase también como diccionario = dict()

numeropalabras = int(input("¿Cuantas palabras quieres que te pregunte?: "))

for i in range(numeropalabras):
    palabra = input("\nIngrese su palabra en español: ")
    traduccion = input("Ingrese la traducción al francés de {0}: ".format(palabra))
    diccionario[palabra] = traduccion
```

Hay muchas formas de acceder al diccionario, una de ellas es usar el método `.items()` que retorna tuplas con las parejas `(clave, valor)`

Por ejemplo:

```
diccionario = {}

numeropalabras = int(input("¿Cuantas palabras quieres que te pregunte?: "))

for i in range(numeropalabras):
    palabra = input("\nIngrese su palabra en español: ")
    traduccion = input("Ingrese la traducción al francés de {0}: ".format(palabra))
    diccionario[palabra] = traduccion

for palabra, traduccion in diccionario.items():
    print('La traducción de "{0}" es "{1}."'.format(palabra, traduccion))
```

Uso el método [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) para dar formato a las cadenas de los `print()`, por si quieres ver como funciona.

Con esto ya deberias poder seguir tu.

**Actualización:**

Para comparar dos string simplemte hace falta hacer:

```
if string1 == strig2:
```

El problema es que te has confundido al usar `{1}`. Esto es para hacer referencia al indice de la tupla de palabras que toma el método de cadenas `.format()`. Es decir, que se usa solo con ese método. Simplemte debes cambiar:

```
if respuesta == "{1}":
```

por:

```
if respuesta == traduccion:
```

Otros apuntes:

- `input()` retorna siempre una cadena por lo que no es necesario esl casting con `str()`
- En la línea `print('\nCuál es la traducción  "{0}"?'.format(palabra, traduccion))` como solo quieres imprimir la variable `palabra` no necesitas pasarle a `format()` la variable `traduccion` basta con:

  `print('\nCuál es la traducción  "{0}"?'.format(palabra))`

Tu código qudaría asi:

```
diccionario = {}

numeropalabras = int(input("¿Cuantas palabras quieres que te pregunte?: "))

for i in range(numeropalabras):
    palabra = str(input("\nIngrese su palabra en español: "))
    traduccion = str(input("Ingrese la traducción al francés de {0}: ".format(palabra)))
    diccionario[palabra] = traduccion

for palabra, traduccion in diccionario.items():
    print('\nCuál es la traducción  "{0}"?'.format(palabra))
    respuesta = input("\nIngrese su respuesta en francés: ")
    if respuesta == traduccion:
        print("Su respuesta es correcta.")
    else:
        print("Su respuesta es incorrecta.")
```

Comment: He editado el código de mi pregunta con el código que me has dado. He añadido una cosilla, para que compare si la respuesta es correcta o incorrecta. Cómo se comparan 2 strings en Python? Me da todo el rato incorrecta.

Comment: @JuanVan12 no debes actualizar usando una respuesta porque para los usuarios que lean esto después queda muy confuso. Espera un momento, voy a editar tu pregunta y mi respuesta a ver si lo hacemos legible a terceros.

Comment: Todo hecho @JuanVan12, mira a ver que tal. Te recomiendo que te mires la documentación o busques en google como se usa cada cosa que te vamos explicando como `string.format()` si quieres ir aprendiendo, de lo contrario esto no te servirá de nada.